# How to remove first few characters from R column values?

Tags: r, regex

I have a column that consists of values that are separated by a "|" and generated this code but it takes everything before the "|", not after. Keep in mind this column is a "Factor".

```
INV | Building One
BO | Building Twenty Five
VC | Corporate

sub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1"
```

How do I remove the first portion before the "|" and keep only everything after in R using 'sub'?

Expected Output:

```
Building One
Building Twenty Five
Corporate
```

Comment: You can also use `read.table` from *base* and *trimws*: `trimws(read.table(text=as.character(df$col1), sep="|")[,2])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression you are looking for is `".*?\\|"`.

- `.` matches all characters
- `*` zero or more times
- `?` make `*` 'lazy'
- `\\|` match "|" which is also a regular expression so it must be escaped

Test:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("INV | Building One", 
                          "BO | Building Twenty Five",
                          "VC | Corporate"))

sub(".*?\\|", "", df$col1)
#> [1] " Building One"         " Building Twenty Five" " Corporate"
```

Here is a brilliant regex cheatsheet I use for this kind of stuff: https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

BTW: `tidyr` comes with a nice little function that would help here:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(col1, into = c("col1", "col2"), sep = "\\|")
#>   col1                  col2
#> 1 INV           Building One
#> 2  BO   Building Twenty Five
#> 3  VC              Corporate
```

It splits your one column into two, which seems plausible here.

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another approach of using `sub`

```
sub(".*\\|\\s+(.*)","\\1",s)
```

such that

```
> sub(".*\\|\\s+(.*)","\\1",s)
[1] "Building One"         "Building Twenty Five"
[3] "Corporate"
```

**Data**

```
s <- c("INV | Building One", "BO | Building Twenty Five", "VC | Corporate")
```